# Access my NAS sites via internet

Tags: subdomain, synology-diskstation

Recently I bought Synology DS 220+. I have set DDNS and issued Let's Encrypt certificate for my domain so domain looks like this: `MyID.synology.me`. But I don't have direct access to my NAS via this domainname or my external IP address because I don't have a white IP address (a static IP without NAT on ISP's side,if I understood correctly)  for which I need to pay to my ISP (with this also comes managing NAT rules on ISP's devices).

I deployed some services like Mediawiki on DSM's native Web Station and pihole and VaultWarden on Docker.

- URL in LAN for accessing MediaWiki is like this: `https://MyID.synology.me/mediawiki`
- URL in LAN for accessing Vaultwarden is like this: `https://vaultwarden.MyID.synology.me`

Inside LAN everything works great, I can access those services with HTTPS.

But I also need access to Mediawiki and Vaultwarden via Internet so I used QuickConnect service for this. I issued another Let's Encrypt certificate for `MyID.direct.quickconnect.to`.
QuickConnect gave me this URL to access my NAS: `https://192-168-1-21.MyID.quickconnect.to` (192.168.1.21 is actually my NAS IP in LAN).

With this URL I can access my Mediawiki page through Internet: `https://192-168-1-21.MyID.quickconnect.to/mediawiki`. But I can't get how I could access my Vaultwarden. Could you give me some tips how to do it?

Maybe somehow I can change Vaultwarden's location to `https://MyID.synology.me/vaultwarden` so I could access it via `https://192-168-1-21.MyID.quickconnect.to/vaultwarden` in the internet?

Comment: It’s impossible to access 192.168.1.21 from outside your network.

Comment: I am not accessing my NAS from Internet with 192.168.1.21 address. 192-168-1-21 is just a part of domain name provided by QuickConnect.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by a "white IP address". Have you opened the ports, and forwarded those ports to your NAS, if is a the DDNS is generating https://MyID.synology.me/ then simply forwarding the port should be enough unless you are behinda CGNAT

Comment: I mean static IP without NAT on ISP's side (if I understood correctly). I forwarded necessary ports to my NAS. I can access my mediawiki on NAS through Internet via https://192-168-1-21.MyID.quickconnect.to/mediawiki
I need to access also my Bitwarden.

Comment: So are you behind a CGNAT? If you are behind a CGNAT you won't be able to host the services, or specifically, host them and make them accessible outside of your network.

Comment: Well I can access my mediawiki, DSM and some other services.

Comment: It really sounds like "Synology DDNS" isn't just DDNS but also a relay service. Can you check what IP address the "MyID" domain name resolves to? If it shows an IP address that doesn't belong to your ISP, that would mean it is a relay service (which might be designed to work through NATs).

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the Reverse Proxy feature, that allows you to host multiple sites on one ip/port/cert.  by using quick connect (a reverse tunnel) you have solved the reachability issue, but now you need to tell the NAS how to distinguish between the sites. https://mikesolin.com/2020/07/07/setting-up-synologys-reverse-proxy-server/